# Best resource to learn How to Create AJAX enabled User Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, asp.net-ajax

In our project, we use lot of User Controls.  None of them supports AJAX.  We use UpdatePanel for partial page rendering.  There is no proper client side functions for the controls.

I used to create normal JS functions in the ascx page itself.  I guess it is not the standard way to add client functionality to a User Control. However i can achieve all the things which i required , with out using any such standards. But when considering the maintainability, it is tough & it is hard to make changes & not scalable.

So i want to learn the proper way to create AJAX enabled User Controls.  Just like how Telerik & other 3rd party controls create User Controls. What is the recommended way to create such controls by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific about the problem with Update Panel??

To use inbuilt ajax,
1. You need a ScriptManager
2. Put all necessary controls within Update Panel

Since you are using User Controls, its better to add ScriptManager in the main page where the User Control is added. Otherwise it might give an error saying multiple ScriptManager found.

Comment: Hi Nidhin, I am not very comfortable with Update Panel, It requires a postback anyhow. even though it is a partial postback, it goes through the entire page life cycle behind the scene.

Comment: Are you using a button for sending the data? Just make sure all the controls are inside update panel

Comment: Nidhin, Please see acarter's comment below. i am expecting something like that.

Answer (score 0):

UpdatePanel uses AJAX and is easy to use, however, if you want true client side controls, i.e. only call the server when you need too, then it's probably best to look elsewhere.

If you want to write your own controls, I'd recommended reading about some JavaScript design patterns, specifically the module pattern.  If you have decent JavaScript skills, it's extremely easy to create controls with the help of jQuery - may as well make it a jQuery plugin.  You might want to check out some client side MVC/MVVM frameworks like AngularJS or Knockout might be enough, because at least they'll help you with data bindings so it's less painful to manage the data on the client side and get it back to the server.

But, unless you're doing some that no one else has done before, why not use some existing controls by Telerik or DevExpress for example?

Example of module pattern (there's a bunch of different ways to do module pattern, this is just one):

```
var myModule = {
    /* PROPERTIES */
    prop1: 'sdfsdf',
    prop2: 123,

    /* FUNCTIONS */
    func1: function () {
        alert('!!!');
    }
}

/* example use of module */
alert(myModule.prop1);
myModule.func1();
```

You'll also need to have a good understanding of events in JavaScript.  For example, if you wanted to create a client side grid (there's millions already available for free), you'd need to handle click and text changed types of events.  i.e. to handle paging, sorting, filtering and any other feature you might want out of your grid.

**Edit:** just created a basic JSFiddle to give you an example of a really basic client side control using a jQuery plugin.  It doesn't work perfectly, but thought it might give you an idea of where to start if you wanted to try making your own controls.

http://jsfiddle.net/pwqmenwx/1/